# HTML <li> can't go in <div>

Tags: html, list, tags, w3c, w3c-validation

I am currently coding a website for a school project, and I have boxes that grow on a mouse hover that are in a div. An example of one grow div:

```
    <div class="grow">
         <div class="title3">Experience</div> 
         <div class="mainbox">
         <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In here, I need a `<li>` to list my industry certifications, but then it won't validate. So I was trying this:

```
  <div class="grow">
          <div class="title3">Experience</div> 
         <div class="mainbox">
         <p class="text"><li>
         <ul>Sample</ul>
         <ul>Sample</ul></li></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But then this doesn't validate. What should I do instead, or is there another good alternative to a list that looks good?

Comment: It's `<ul> <li> </li> </ul> ` not `<li> <ul> </ul> </li>  `.

Comment: `<ul>` = unordered list, `<li>` = list-item. The items go in the list like @Dai suggestion.

Comment: Weird, this is the second time today I've seen someone flip the ul and li in a list. `<li>` must be children of `<ul>` or `<ol>`. It can't be the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including an UL inside of a LI, you need revert. First you need add   UL and inside of this tag, add the LI you need.

```html
<div class="grow">
          <div class="title3">Experience</div> 
         <div class="mainbox">
         <ul>
            <li>Sample 1</li>
            <li>Sample 2</li>
            <li>Sample 3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Of course! Silly mistake on my part, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

UL wraps LIs.

```
<ul><li>....</li></ul>
```